# Read conflict when empty sub-form

Tags: ms-access

I use MS Access as a front with Mysql as the database. I have set up a form in which I have to validate data entry due to an increased risk of duplicate entries in my db. In order to minimise the risk of duplicate entries, the validation form has a sub-form showing the results of a "view" from Mysql with previously existing names which seem similar. Upon validation, the VBA code will add to the record a timestamp and the current user.

When I started testing, I continuously received a "write conflict" error. After extensive search I found out that this had to do with the sub-form. So I have the following situation:

- Sub-form contains data - my validation form works perfectly fine and code is executed correctly;
- Sub-form contains no result - my validation form has a "write conflict" and my code cannot be executed correctly;

Sub-form data, by its set-up, cannot be edited (which is also not required).

I now ran out of ideas on how to resolve this, so I revert to this community.

---RESOLVED
For this community, I have resolved my issue by setting
Record Selectors to "No" and
Navigation Buttons to "No"
on the subform. No conflicts anymore.

Answer (score 0):

For this community, I have resolved my issue by setting Record Selectors to "No" and Navigation Buttons to "No" on the subform. No conflicts anymore.